# How to build a model with multivalue input and output in dynamic folders?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, multi-values

I am trying to build a model that gets a multivalue as an **Input** which is located in different folders within a main folder, and stores the **Output** in new folders that have the same structure like in the input, but with different pathway.

I tried to select the data with a "multivalue iterator", then simultaneously create a folder with "parse path" (=x) that has a c:...\main_folder\%x%.

there are two problems with that:

- I **get just a single output** (I'm running the data through alot of processes) from my multivalue input. How can I fix that? I want that every vector\raster will have a new name (%oldname%_%newname%), and each **will be exported to a different folder**.

So, for example, I want to take a 2 files:

c:...\main_folder\folder1\vector1

c:...\main_folder\folder2\vector2

and I want that each of them will be exported like this:

x:\outputs\main_folder\folder1\vector1_cliped

x:\outputs\main_folder\folder2\vector2_cliped

- I want a dynamic pathway, so the tool could create the folders in the main folder by itself, and because there are a lot of sub-folders within the sub-folders, I want to create only the folders that contain the selected data.

Also, the **folders structure may change**, so I do not want to create a mother-folder and then create more folders with preconditioning.

I should mention I **do not have any experience with python and scripting**, but I believe that if you are able to give me a script to merge into my modelbuilder, then I'll learn how to edit it a little to match my data.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Our protocols can take a bit of getting used to but this [**Meta Question**](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/what-makes-a-good-question) may be helpful to you.  As it stands I think your question has too many "questions" within it to be suitable for the Q&A format used here so I recommend trying to focus your most important question into a single Question.

Comment: well, if I would have to choose, i think the most tricky question is how to get multivalue outputs in a dynamic folder. I saw here a qusetion about the output, but I didn't understand it so much (python scripting) and it does not answer how to export it to a dynamic folder's pathway.

Comment: Now is the ideal time to edit your Question to focus it on that.  You may well find that in getting an Answer to that first Question you may learn enough to answer some of the other questions.

Comment: I didn't know I can edit my question. nice.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to include the version of ArcGIS for Desktop that you are using, please?

Comment: Are you running the model in batch mode, or is there an iterator in there?  Also, a screenshot of the model can help with a problem this thorny.